# How to solve $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}\right)$ Solved

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals

I stuck in this limit, I tried to solve it and gets 1/2 as result. Yet, I was wrong because I forgot a square. Please need help!

$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}\right)$

Note: it's $+\infty$

Thanks in advance

Update: I actually solved it, and this is the way that I wanted to:

$\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}\right)\:=\:\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{x}}\right)=\:\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}{x}\right)+\sqrt{x}}}\right)=\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}+1\right)}\right)=\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}}+1\right)}\right)=\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}+1}\right)=\frac{0}{2}=0$

Thanks for your two answers guys. I really appreciate it ! This community is awesome !

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by conjugates to rewrite your expression to contain a difference of squares?

Comment: @user170231 I'm stuck in this point: $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}+1}\right)}\right)$ What to do next?

Comment: To prevent this question from remaining open, you may add your *own* solution of the problem as an answer and even *accept* that. This is much better than just editing a "Solved" into the title ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I didn't want really to accept one answer, because all of this guys has a correct one, but thanks for your suggestion. I'll choose the first one, just to close this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}-\sqrt x&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}-\sqrt x\right)\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}+\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}+\sqrt x}\\
&\le \frac{\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}-\sqrt x\right)\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}+\sqrt x\right)}{1+\sqrt x}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}{1+\sqrt x}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}\\
&\to 0\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you solve it please in a basic way, we didn't study how to solve limits like what you've just did, so we can't use it

Comment: @AmineMarzouki comparison is quite a basic way to show that a limit is zero. It's not clear what you mean by more basic.

Comment: @Scounged Well, We have different educational systems, so I don't know what do you mean by comparison. We have some limits "tips you could say" but none of them are here in those 2 answers

Comment: @AmineMarzouki By comparison, I mean that H.v.E chooses to evaluate a simpler expression, knowing that it's easier to calculate that limit directly than the original, whereafter its possible to draw conclusions about the original limit from the limit calculated instead. What are the limits "tips" you mentioned, and what is your educational level?

Comment: @Scounged Well, now this year, I have second year of bacalaureat. Tips like: 1. If |f(x)-1|<g(x) and lim g(x)= 0 then lim f(x) = l (as x approach to x0)  2.If f(x)<=g(x) and lim f(x) = +inf then lim g(x) = +inf 3. if g(x)<= f(x) <= h(x) and lim g(x) = lim h(x) = l then lim f(x) = l . I didn't understand you well, what's H.v.E. Could you give me a link to learn those tips? I'll answer you tomorrow I must go to sleep, it's 12:16 AM and I must wake up at 6:30 AM

Comment: @AmineMarzouki One could argue that "tip 3" was used here:
$g(x)=0$, $f(x)=${your original expression}, $h(x)=${H.v.E's expression after the inequality sign}. $\lim g(x)=\lim h(x)=0$. This isn't really a mechanical "technique". It's about realizing just how much you can use those simple tricks to calculate limits.

Comment: @Scounged what is "H.v.E's expression" first? Could you give me some links to know more about it?

Comment: @AmineMarzouki Your original expression: $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}=f(x)$, H.v.E's "expression" in his answer above: $\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}-\sqrt x\right)\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}+\sqrt x\right)}{1+\sqrt x}= h(x)$ a.k.a, the one directly after the inequality sign. Nothing more to know about it. It's just an expression. But it's easier to take the limit of that than the original expression.

Comment: @Scounged Oh, it's make sense. "Rationalizing" isn't it? Thanks though

Comment: @AmineMarzouki I'm not sure what it's called, as I'm not a native English speaker, but I have seen the methodology earlier. We don't really call it by name at the place where I'm studying.

Comment: @Scounged Ok thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

If ${\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0}$ and you are taking a limit of the form
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x + f(x)} - \sqrt{x}$$
Then you can proceed by writing the limit as
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x} \bigg(\sqrt{1 + {f(x) \over x}} - 1\bigg)$$
Since $\sqrt{1 + \epsilon} = 1 + {1 \over 2} \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$, the limit will be the same as 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
In the case at hand, $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}$, which is bounded by
for example $\sqrt{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x}} = \sqrt 2 x^{1 \over 4}$. Hence the limit will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, I will use $y=\sqrt{x}$ The limit becomes

$$
\lim_{y\to \infty}( \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{1+y}}-y)= \lim_{y\to \infty}( \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{1+y}}-y)\frac{\sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{1+y}}+y}{\sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{1+y}}+y}
=\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+y}}{\sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{1+y}}+y} \\
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1/y+1}}{\sqrt{y^2+y^2\sqrt{1/y^4+1/y^3}}+y}\\
 =\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1/y+1}}{\sqrt{y^2(1+\sqrt{1/y^4+1/y^3})}+y}\\
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1/y+1}}{|y|\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/y^4+1/y^3}}+y}\\
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1/y+1}}{y\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/y^4+1/y^3}}+y}\\
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1/y+1}}{y\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/y^4+1/y^3}}+1\right)}\\
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{1/y+1}}{\sqrt{y}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/y^4+1/y^3}}+1\right)}\\
\to \frac{1}{\infty \cdot 2}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

If we have $f(x)/x^{1/2} \to 0,$ where $f(x) > 0,$ then the MVT gives

$$(x+f(x))^{1/2} - x^{1/2} = 1/(2c_x^{1/2})\cdot f(x) \le f(x)/2x^{1/2}  \to 0.$$

Above $c_x \in (x,x+f(x)),$ so we're OK. In this problem $f(x) = (1+x^{1/2})^{1/2},$ so the desired limit is $0.$